# perf .data has information (size) but appears to be empty

Tags: ubuntu, perf, stress-testing

Have an android device I'm running perf on. I'm running tests for up to an hour sometimes, tracking cpu capacity and cpu frequency while running stressapptest. Conversion from .data to .txt seems to be hit and miss or just viewing data. Sometimes I'll get a large text file, which is what I want. Other times I'll get a blank text file, of size 0. I mention stressapptest, but this problem isn't exclusive to that program.

I run this all over a serial connection. I start by removing old files (the old stressapptest log, the old perf .data file & .txt file). Perf & stressapptest run in background w/ ampersand.

```
rm -f STRESS.txt ; rm -f perf_record.data ; rm -f perf_record.txt ; /vendor/sbin/perf record -e power:cpu_capacity,power:cpu_frequency -a -o perf_record.data -v & stressapptest -s 3600 -M 1024 -v 20 -l STRESS.txt  &
```

Commands run after stressapptest passes/fails, etc...

```
killall perf ; /vendor/sbin/perf script -i perf_record.data > perf_record.txt
```

This is an example of what perf spits out when I kill it, before I convert it, took this today:

```
[ perf record: Woken up 409 times to write data ]
failed to write feature 2
failed to write feature 8
failed to write feature 9
failed to write feature 14
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 105.746 MB perf_record.data ]
```

If instead of converting, I choose to just view the .data file on the device with

```
/vendor/sbin/perf script -i perf_record.data
```

I get no output. The .data file is large in size but the .txt file is exactly 0 bytes. No information in it whatsoever. If I run perf script -D to get raw trace data, I get a lot. Unintelligible (to me) but here is a snippet:

```
0 0 0x900 [0x60]: PERF_RECORD_MMAP -1/0: [0xffffff85936a8000(0x13000) @ 0]: x [a
th_rate_atheros]                                                                
                                                                                
0x960 [0x58]: event: 1                                                          
.                                                                               
. ... raw event: size 88 bytes                                                  
.  0000:  01 00 00 00 01 00 58 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 ^C34m 00 00 00 00 00 00  ].a
thero........                                                                   
.  0040:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................     
.  0050:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........
```

I also see there's a -d argument I could provide to go into debug mode. I can try that if it will glean more information about the recording. I've run this same series of actions multiple times, and as I said I sometimes get a file w/ data and sometimes I don't.

Can anyone think of a reason why my .txt files are blank?